# Error Generate APK from ionic and angular from android studio (Illegal char <:> at index)

Tags: android, angular, android-studio, ionic-framework, apk

I'm getting the following error. I generated a project in ionic and angular, I generated the build and the android but when I want to generate the apk from android studio it is giving me the following error :

Illegal char <:> at index 43: io.ionic.starter.app-mergeDebugResources-30:/values/values.xml

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed (Failed to compile values resource file path :
> \android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\debug\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml. Cause: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 43: io.ionic.starter.app-mergeDebugResources-30:/values/values.xml). Check logs for more details.

I cleaned up the project, reassembled the Android package, checked the value.xml file and it's OK